# $_SESSION variable gets set incorrectly, how to fix?

Tags: php, session, wamp

I am running WAMP server 3.1.9 (PHP 7.2.18, Apache 2.4.39) and I have the following question regarding PHP sessions.
Consider the following code:

test1.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 1;
echo $_SESSION['test']." set";
?>
```

test2.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['test'];
$_SESSION['test'] = 2;
?>
```

When I use a browser and load test1.php I get the output "1 set" like expected. But when I then immediately load test2.php I get "2" instead of "1". It is acting as if test2.php has been executed twice and the second time the output is allowed. I am not sure what is causing this behavior. Please help.

Comment: I just tried it in internet explorer and it works correctly! It displays "1" and then "2" if I reload test2.php page. In Chrome the strange behavior is still there though.

Comment: turn caching off. right click, inspect, it'll be somewhere in there

Comment: @Fort Try this in incognito mode and see if this persists.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `$_SESSION['test'] = 2;` line and just echo out the session var in test2.php?

Comment: If I remove the $_SESSION['test'] = 2; line the output is "1". Also, If i disable cache in Chrome (developer only) then the code works fine. Isnt it possible to make it work with caching enabled. It seems like a serious problem.

Comment: The problem in this particular instance seems rather construed, deliberately overwriting an already set value … If you have actual, sensitive functionality that must not run twice, no matter what causes a second request (might not be the cache, might be the user deliberately reloading a page, …) - then implement some logic to check for that, by storing the info that it has already run _into_ the session as well.

Answer (score -3):

The session key `$_SESSION['test']` is the same that's why it does not work in a browser. if open these files in the different browser so it will work, besides you need to use the different key at the same time, which means if session is set named as `test` you can not use 'test' key for another session.
use session like see in codding...

test1.php:

```
    <?php 
     session_start();
     $_SESSION['test'] = 1;
     echo $_SESSION['test']." set";
    ?>
```

test2.php:

```
    <?php
     session_start();
     echo $_SESSION['another-test'];
     $_SESSION['another-test'] = 2;
    ?>
```

if you want to use same key, you need to destroy the previous session are stored using the function...

```
session_destroy();
```

or

```
unset($_SESSION['test']);
```